# Вывод списка процессов C# WinForms

Tags: c#, .net

В общем проблема такая, что никак не вывести список процессов (всех) в label.

```
case 7:
label2.Text = null;
string processi = string.Empty;
foreach (System.Diagnostics.Process winProc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    processi = string.Format("Process " + winProc.Id + ": " + winProc.ProcessName + "\n");
    /*MessageBox.Show("Process " + winProc.Id + ": " + winProc.ProcessName);*/
    break;
}
show_information(processi);
break;
```

Вывод идет через

```
private void show_information(string some_inf)
{
    label2.Text = null;
    some = some_inf.ToCharArray();
    some_count = 0;
    tmr = new Timer();
    tmr.Interval = 10;
    tmr.Tick += new EventHandler(tmr_Tick);
    tmr.Start();

}
```

и

```
private void tmr_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (some_count < some.Length)
    {
        label2.Text += some[some_count].ToString();
        some_count++;
    }
    else
        tmr.Stop(); 
}
```

Проблема в том что выводит только один процесс, хром..
Как это можно исправить, что бы выводились все процессы?
И есть еще кусок кода от преподавателя, но я не понимаю как его использовать:

```
private void getProcess(bool nd)
{
    switch (nd)
    {
        case true:
            if (!why)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
                {
                    process[i] = new ColumnHeader();
                    process[i].Width = 600;
                    switch (i)
                    {
                        case 0: process[i].Text = "Имя"; break;
                        case 1: process[i].Text = "Путь"; break;
                        case 2: process[i].Text = "Id"; break;
                        case 3: process[i].Text = "Память"; break;
                    }
                }
                listView1.Columns.AddRange(process);
                listView1.Columns[0].Width = 600;
                why = true;
            }
            break;
        default:
            if (why)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i > 4; i++)
                    if (process[i] != null)
                        process[i].Dispose();
                listView1.Columns[0].Width = 600;
                why = false;
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Закомментированный кусок кода работает как надо, но мне нужен вывод в label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вроде у вас банальная очепятка - вместо того чтобы добавить строку, вы каждый раз ее заменяете. Надо заменить `processi = string.Format("Process " + winProc.Id + ": " + winProc.ProcessName + "\n");` на `processi += string.Format("Process " + winProc.Id + ": " + winProc.ProcessName + "\n");`

Кстати лучше использовать StringBuilder.

Comment: Я вас уверяю, и так и так пытался, и даже без объявления переменной processi, а сразу запись в label (label1.Text += ...), всё время выводится один процесс хрома. Можно по подробней на счет бюлдера?

Comment: А break зачем? У вас цикл один раз работает.

Comment: да, Вы правы этого не заметил, убрал и пошли все процессы. Большое спасибо!

Comment: Ага, и приняли вы неправильный ответ. Я нашел ответ, а мне фиг. :(

Comment: Я к сожалению не знал, что не могу выбрать сразу два ответа правильными, я использовал код из другого ответа, с вашей подсказкой)

Answer (score 2):

Попробуйте следующее:

```
var procList = new List<string>();
foreach (var winProc in System.Diagnostics.Process.GetProcesses())
{
    procList.Add(string.Format("Process: {0}, Name: {1}",winProc.Id, winProc.ProcessName));
}
```

Comment: Большое спасибо, если убрать break; из цикла, всё работает как надо